# How to get nested json for dropdown value

Tags: angularjs

Here is my json

```
This.selectedColumn = null;
            This.dynamicCmbItems = [{
                id: 1,
                label: 'aLabel',
                subItem: [
                    {
                        name: 'aSubItem1'
                    },
                     {
                         name: 'aSubItem2'
                     },
                      {
                          name: 'aSubItem3'
                      }
                ]
            }, {
                id: 2,
                label: 'bLabel',
                subItem: { name: 'bSubItem' }
            }];
```

In html I have two `<select>`s, first one displays label and second one should display subitem->name of selected label Eg: if I select aLabel in my first dropdown then second dropdown should show subitem of aLabel. I am able to load the first dropdown. How should I load second dropdown?

html file:

```
<select ng-options="item.label for item in vm.dynamicCmbItems track by item.id" ng-model="vm.selectedColumn" ></select>
<select ng-options="item.subItem.name for item in vm.dynamicCmbItems" ng-model="vm.selected"></select>
```

i want to do something like

```
<select ng-options="item.subItem.name for item in vm.dynamicCmbItems | fileter: {item.label : vm.selectedColumn}" ng-model="vm.selected"></select>
```

Comment: it's not a JSON, it's JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-model` on the first select already binds the whole object for you, so in the second select you can just use

```
<select ng-options="item.name for item in vm.selectedColumn.subItems" ng-model="vm.selected"></select>
```